# GetSelectedItem from TableView JavaFX issue

Tags: java, javafx

I have some issue with getSelectedRow. I can't make method that puts text from table's row to textfield. I tried to make `table.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {getTextFromSelectedRow();});`

but everytime got `Cannot infer functional interface type`.

Help me please with that method. I need to get selected item from row when it's clicked.

And is it right that I do everything in Controller class?

Controller class

```
package com.cascado.application.application;

import static com.cascado.application.common.Constants.REGEX;

import com.cascado.application.common.User;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<User> table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<User, String> idColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<User, String> firstNameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<User, String> lastNameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TextField firstNameField;
    @FXML
    private TextField lastNameField;
    @FXML
    private TextField idField;
    private ObservableList<User> users;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("ID"));
        firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("firstName"));
        lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("lastName"));
        users = table.getItems();
    }
    @FXML
    private void addButton(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        users.add(newUser(0, 1, 2));
        table.setItems(users);
        clearFields();
    }

    private void selectRow(){
        table.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {
            getTextFromSelectedRow();
        });
        getTextFromSelectedRow();
    }

    private void getTextFromSelectedRow(){
        User selectedUser = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        idField.setText(selectedUser.getID());
        firstNameField.setText(selectedUser.getFirstName());
        lastNameField.setText(selectedUser.getLastName());
    }

    @FXML
    private void updateButton(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    }

    @FXML
    private void deleteButton(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    }

    private String[] fieldsTextArray(){
        return (idField.getText() + REGEX + firstNameField.getText() + REGEX + lastNameField.getText()).split(REGEX);
    }

    private void clearFields(){
        firstNameField.clear();
        lastNameField.clear();
        idField.clear();
    }

    private User newUser(int id, int firstName, int lastName){
        // values in textfields message array
        return new User(fieldsTextArray()[id], fieldsTextArray()[firstName], fieldsTextArray()[lastName]);
    }

}
```

FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox prefHeight="389.0" prefWidth="407.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="com.cascado.application.application.Controller">
  <children>
    <MenuBar VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
      <menus>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Quit" />
               </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
          <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About Database" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
      </menus>
    </MenuBar>
    <AnchorPane maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="353.0" prefWidth="407.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
             <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" text="ID" />
             <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="50.0" text="First name" />
             <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="84.0" text="Last name" />
             <TextField layoutX="87.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="256.0" fx:id="idField"/>
            <TextField layoutX="87.0" layoutY="47.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="256.0" fx:id="firstNameField"/>
            <TextField layoutX="87.0" layoutY="84.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="256.0" fx:id="lastNameField"/>
            <HBox layoutX="14.0" layoutY="120.0">
               <children>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="128.0" text="Add" onAction="#addButton"/>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="125.0" text="Update" onAction="#updateButton"/>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="125.0" text="Delete" onAction="#deleteButton"/>
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <TableView layoutX="13.0" layoutY="151.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="378.0" fx:id="table">
              <columns>
                <TableColumn prefWidth="48.1036491394043" text="ID" fx:id="idColumn"/>
                <TableColumn prefWidth="149.6151885986328" text="First name" fx:id="firstNameColumn"/>
                  <TableColumn prefWidth="179.3848114013672" text="Last name" fx:id="lastNameColumn"/>
              </columns>
            </TableView>
         </children>
    </AnchorPane>
  </children>
</VBox>
```

Application class

```
package com.cascado.application.application;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Application extends javafx.application.Application {

    public static void run(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(this.getClass().getResource("/resources.fxml"));
        Parent parent = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Database");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

REGEX class

```
package com.cascado.application.common;

public class Constants {
    public static final String REGEX = "@#!#@";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import is wrong.

Don't use:

```
java.awt.event.MouseEvent
```

Use:

```
javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent
```